# Cannot upload Adobe InDesign file

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager, files

I'm having trouble trying to upload an InDesign file to my EE site. I've added the following to the `system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php` file `application/x-indesign` however upon uploading the file I'm shown an error message:

**File not allowed.**

Does anyone know a way around this? I've successfully added a photoshop file to the mime list and that works perfectly fine.

Here's a small slice of the mime $whitelist array

```
'application/x-dvi', // .dvi
'application/x-gtar', // .gtar
'application/x-gzip', // .gz
'application/x-indesign', // .indd
'application/x-photoshop', // .psd
'application/x-rar-compressed', // .rar
'application/x-stuffit', // .sit
```

Thank you.

*Edit:*

EE Version 2.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of EE are you using? Modern (2+) use an array to identify mime type allowances. In my version I'm looking at (2.9.2), it looks like this:

```
$mimes = array(
                'ai'    =>  'application/postscript',
                'aif'   =>  'audio/x-aiff',
                'aifc'  =>  'audio/x-aiff',
                'aiff'  =>  'audio/x-aiff',
                'avi'   =>  'video/x-msvideo',
                'bin'   =>  'application/macbinary',
                'bmp'   =>  'image/bmp',
                 ... and so on ...
);
```

So you'd want to add this:

```
                'indd'  =>  'application/octet-stream',
```

OR

```
                'indd'  =>  'application/x-indesign',
```

OR

```
                'indd'  =>  'application/x-adobe-indesign',
```

OR to be safe

```
                'indd'  =>  array('application/octet-stream',        
                                  'application/x-indesign',        
                                  'application/x-adobe-indesign'),
```

You'll have to try them all, the internet is reporting a few different things and it's quicker to just test these variants and see what works.

So I'm not sure what version you are running, but that appears to be a malformed mime type array (verified to be this format as far back as 2.5.5).

**Edit**

As Kieran McClung mentioned,  EllisLab has switched to a new mimetype detection library for 2.10+. At this point, we now have a $whitelist flat array instead of a $mimes array that can have a second layer of depth. I'm pretty sure adding

```
'application/octet-stream'
```

was the fix, although Keiran said all three were needed, which would have resulted in a $whitelist array that looked like this

```
$whitelist = array(
    'application/csv', // .csv
    'application/epub+zip', // .epub
    'application/excel', // .csv, .xl, .xls
    'application/mac-binhex40', // .hqx
    ... and so on ...
    'application/octet-stream', // .indd
    'application/x-indesign', // .indd
    'application/x-adobe-indesign', // .indd
);
```

And that got things whipped into shape!

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to mention my EE version. The $mimes array you put above certainly looks more robust however it's causing issues for me. 

I've downloaded a fresh copy of EE 2.10.1 and it contains the $whitelist array with the layout as seen in my original question, however an older download (2.9.2) contains the $mimes array you've put above. I tried adding application/x-adobe-indesign and even copying the $mimes array in it's entirety but unfortunately it's not worked.

Comment: I needed all three mime types as you stated however it seems from 2.10.1 onwards EllisLab are using a new way of checking file types: https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/fileinfo-in-2-10-0

Comment: I see that, is your issue resolved? If so I'll edit my question to adapt for the change in EE 2.10.1. I've played around with it, but it's still a little too new for me to dump into production anywhere. Yeah, I just took a peak at an install and they switched it up.

Comment: Yeah sorry, If you just add the bit about 2.10.1 I'll mark as accepted. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: No problem! I added the edits. Glad to help.